# 3 Image Transition Opacity on Click Issue

Tags: html, css

I'm developing a site and the navigation buttons have 3 states as usual, the initial idle state, a hover state and a click state and a state to show that's the page your on.

I thought I'd add some nice transitions to the :hover and :active states, and while the :hover works nicely I can't seem to get the :active to work as I want.

If you take a look at this fiddle you'll have a clearer idea of what I'm trying to achieve:
http://jsfiddle.net/number8pie/3BvhM/2/

As you can see on :hover there is an opacity transition that I think looks quite nice, but when you click the link I want about_us.png and about_us_hover.png to be set to opacity 0 (using the transition) and about_us_active.png to be left visible.

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul class="right"> <!-- no closing tag on <li> so that the whitespace between elements is removed-->
  <li id="about-us">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">
      <div class="icon-cont">
        <img class="top" src="http://s28.postimg.org/7u46xdbjd/about_us.png">
        <img class="middle" src="http://s28.postimg.org/mel9s76i1/about_us_hover.png">
        <img class="bottom" src="http://s28.postimg.org/bt1eg706h/about_us_active.png">
      </div>
      <span class="nav-text">about us</span>
    </a>
  <li id="products">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="nav-text">products</span></a>
  <li id="the-team">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="nav-text">the team</span></a>
  <li id="environment">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="nav-text">environment</span></a>
  <li id="contact">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="nav-text">contact</span></a>
</ul>
```

And the CSS:

```
ul li {
  height: 56px;
  width: 56px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'RobotoLight';
  font-size: 21px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.icon-cont {
  position: relative;
  height: 56px;
  width: 56px;
  margin: 0;
}

.icon-cont img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.icon-cont img.top {
  z-index: 30;
}

.icon-cont img.middle {
  z-index: 20;
}

.icon-cont img.bottom {
  z-index: 10;
}

.icon-cont img.top:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

.icon-cont img.top:active {
  opacity: 0;
}

.icon-cont img.middle:active {
  opacity: 0;
}

.nav-text {
  font-size: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1000px;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any hep and or suggestions.

Comment: I'm not sure if that can be done through css, would a javascript solution be acceptable?

Comment: I'm not completely opposed to the idea of using javascript, but only really if it's not possible with CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do most of this using some CSS trickery- namely by relying on the `:checked` state of a sibling hidden input to control the appearance of a `label`.

To set the state depending on the current page, you'll likely need to use some JS to identify the page, then apply a suitable class to the element in question.

This will work for on/off click states. If you want a depress (mousedown) state, you should likely use a `button` element instead of anchor `a` tags in your code to apply `:active` to.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3BvhM/3/)

[**(alternate demo using a button and `:active`)**](http://jsfiddle.net/3BvhM/5/)

HTML

```
<input type='checkbox' id='menuItem' />
<label for='menuItem'>i</label>
```

CSS

```
input {
    display:none;
}
label {
    display:inline-block;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    color:white;
    font-size:1.5em;
    font-style:italic;
    font-family:arial;
    background:lightgreen;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    transition:all 200ms ease-in;
}
label:after {
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
    content:'';
    border:4px solid white;
    border-radius:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    left:6px;
    top:6px;
    opacity:0;
    transition:all 200ms ease-in;
}
label:hover:after {
    opacity:1;
}
input:checked+label {
    background:none;
    color:lightgreen;
}
input:checked+label:after {
    border-color:lightgreen;
}
```

Comment: The current page thing I didn't really need to mention as I set that with a variable using PHP, so I'm fine doing that. Thanks for your answer but I didn't want it checked on or off, I just wanted it to change when the mouse button was depressed and then change back once the mouse button was released. It's pretty close though.

Comment: I can't get this to work properly with the actual images in my original fiddle, instead of text and background colors.

Comment: @number8pie - see here: http://jsfiddle.net/76r8a/ your selectors are off, that said- I'd swap out the background image, and not have seperate image elements

Comment: Ok that's sorted it, exactly the effect I was after using only CSS. I've edited it slightly but It's what you suggested and it works great. http://jsfiddle.net/number8pie/g4Smb/ Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here it is using javascript. I add a class to the link onmousedown and use that to add the active styles. I've used plain js as I'm not sure if you're using jQuery or some other DOM manipulation library. The code is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/John_C/xsdnL/3/

```
var navLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-link');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(navLinks, function(link) {
    link.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
        this.className += " active";    
    }, false);
    link.addEventListener("mouseup", function(){
        this.className = "nav-link";    
    }, false);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer John, that is almost what I'm after although when the mouse button is released after the click I wanted it to go to it's original state. If you can edit the fiddle to do this (I'm not very fluent in javascript) and there's no way of doing it in CSS I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Here's a new fiddle with a 'mouseup' event. If it fits your needs I'll edit my answer accordingly. http://jsfiddle.net/John_C/xsdnL/1/ You should probably hold off on accepting my answer to see if someone else has a pure css solution.

Comment: I'll give it until 16:30 (GMT) to see if there's a CSS answer, but if not I'll accept this. I've got exactly the effect I was looking for just altering some of the CSS in your second fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/number8pie/R6RpB/ all I've changed is added faster transitions to the mousedown. Exactly the effect I was after.

Comment: Thanks for the help John I'll keep your code handy it will come in useful one day, but SW4 has worked out a way of doing it with CSS only. I appreciate your help on this.